# SQL Query help in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

done
//my attempt not working

```
SELECT *  
FROM Placement, Internship  
WHERE Placement.i_code=Internship.code   
WHERE Student.f_id <> Internship.f_id
```

[INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN cannot be used]

Relationship table:

![Relationship table][1]

Comment: You didn't use Student table in your from clause.so clearly it won't work, and why you don't want to use join?

Comment: Please embed the table schema in the question itself, so it's self-contained. If you link external references like imageshack, they're bound to die at some point in the future leaving your question orphan of essential info.

Comment: You have 2 **WHERE** clauses in your query, the second one needs to be **AND** for a start ^_^ however can you simplify your requirements as it makes for confusing reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT Student.*
FROM Student, Placement, InterShip
WHERE Placement.i_code=Internship.code   
AND Placement.s_code=Student.id
AND Student.f_id <> Internship.f_id
```

BTW: Why don't you want to use Joins?

Comment: I suspect it's homework along the lines of "join these tables without joins"